# Required "owner_id" field is empty in the Database

Tags: django, python-3.x, database

I am trying to save the owner_id that is the same as the Logged In user/Authenticated user. But after I  save the AddressBook form,the database saves the owner id with 'Null' value. Can someone help me knowing where am I going wrong.

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    mobiles = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)

class AddressBook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17) # validators should be a list
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def address(request):
    existing_order = get_user_pending_order(request)
    form = AddressBookForm()
    context = {
        'addressbook': AddressBook.objects.all(),
        'form' : form,
        'order' : existing_order,
    }

    return render(request, 'cart/user_address.html', context)


@login_required
def process_payment(request, order_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':                              
        form = AddressBookForm(request.POST)                  
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return redirect (reverse('update-records', kwargs={'order_id': order_id}))
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import AddressBook

class AddressBookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ADDRESS_TYPE = (
        ('Home', 'Home'),
        ('Work', 'Work'),
    )
    address_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ADDRESS_TYPE, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = AddressBook
        fields = ['name', 'phone_number', 'line1', 'line2', 'city', 'state', 'postcode', 'country','address_type']
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVh0M.png)

Comment: @Alasdair I have added the required things in the question. Let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: @Alasdair I actually need to save the address into DB for future use, and trying to filter the address from the DB with owner_id./ basically the logged in user's address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the form with `commit=False`, set the owner, and then save to the database:

```
if request.method == 'POST':                              
    form = AddressBookForm(request.POST)                  
    if form.is_valid():
        address = form.save(commit=False)
        address.owner = request.user.profile
        address.save()
```

Comment: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: htman47>>": "AddressBook.owner" must be a "UserProfile" instance  ....got this error

Comment: Oh, the foreign key links to `UserProfile`, so use `request.user.profile` instead.